# Highlight an inputText in JSF when a validation error occurs

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a form with a lot of inputText, what I want is to highlight those who are not being filled with correct data.

I tried to use 'component.valid' but it always return that the field is invalid (i.e. fields are always red).

this is the code :

```
<h:inputText value="#{creerPersonne1.nom}" id="nom" 
    style="#{not nom.valid ? 'border-color:red;' : 'border-color:black;'}">
    <f:validateRegex pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$"></f:validateRegex>
</h:inputText>
```

this is the result :

[image: Always invalid]

note that the field is also highlighted when the page is loaded for the first time.

Comment: You wrote `component.valid` in your text but your code shows `nom.valid`. Did you try the (correct) `component.valid`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use `component.valid` instead of `nom.valid`.

`component` is an implicit EL object for the current input component. And `component.valid` calls the `isValid()` method of the server side component. The `id` argument cannot be used this way.

So you should change your code as follows:

```
style="#{ component.valid ? 'border-color:black;' : 'border-color:red;'}"
```

(Not related but you should better use style classes instead of hard coded styles. The valid check works for the `styleClass` attribute as well).

Comment: Indeed, I thought that component had to be replaced by the actual ID of the component :/

Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I just learned the hard way that those won't work without the dependancy "hibernate-validator"