# Validation failed javascript callback in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a template in which I can add a CSS error class to a div when the validation of a component has failed and it renders a pretty nice effect on the browser.

Now, **I don't need to add a css class to a component** ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993615/highlight-an-inputtext-in-jsf-2-0-when-a-validation-error-occurs) won't help me), but rather I need to change the css of the html that surrounds it, this is pretty simple with jQuery, however I can't seem to find a javascript callback for failed validation, is this possible? I'm also using primefaces (in case they provide such capabilities).

Markup:

```
<div class="control-group ERROR_CLASS_GOES_HERE_IF_VALIDATION_FAILED">
   <label class="control-label">Input value:</label>
   <div class="controls">
      <h:inputText class=" inputbox" type="text" required="true" /> <!--Component that can fail -->
   </div>
</div>
```

if the input text is empty, I need the div that wraps the "control group" to have an extra class. I can turn it into a `<h:panelGroup>` so it is a JSF component but still I wouldn't know how to do it. Javascript seems easier as I can do a:

```
jQuery("#ID_OF_DIV").addClass("error_class")
```

Comment: Yes.You can use `.addClass` to existing div.What's you issue?

Comment: my issue is I don't have a javascript callback for when a component fails. Instead of "onclick", "onmouseover" etc, I need something like "onvalidationfailed"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just let JSF/EL conditionally print the class based on [`FacesContext#isValidationFailed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isValidationFailed%28%29).

```html
<div class="control-group #{facesContext.validationFailed ? 'error_class' : ''}">
```

You only need to ensure that this element is covered by ajax update/render.

Another way would be hooking on the `oncomplete` event of an arbitrary PrimeFaces ajax based component. There's an `args` object available in the scope which in turn has a `validationFailed` property. E.g. `<p:commandButton oncomplete>` or even `<p:ajaxStatus oncomplete>`.

```html
<p:ajaxStatus ... oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; args.validationFailed) $('#ID_OF_DIV').addClass('error_class')">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do everything on the client side.

```
     <h:outputText class="samplecls" rendered="#{facesContext.validationFailed}"
              value="Please enter all the required fields">
    </h:outputText>  


    <div class="control-group ERROR_CLASS_GOES_HERE_IF_VALIDATION_FAILED">
       <label class="control-label">Input value:</label>
       <div class="controls">
          <h:inputText class=" inputbox" type="text" required="true" /> <!--Component that can fail -->
       </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript/Jquery**

```
 This class will exist in DOM only validation fails by rendered="#{facesContext.validationFailed}"


  $(window).load(function(){ 
      if($('.samplecls').length>0){
            $("#ID_OF_DIV").addClass("error_class");    
        }
});
```