# Setting CSS class for input in case of ConverterException in JSF

Tags: jsf

The code I'm working on has a page with date inputs, and uses a Converter to transform the input into a Date object. If the input is not a valid date, a ConverterException is thrown.

I'd like to add a light red or pink background to those inputs that had an error. How to achieve this? It is possible to add an error message next to the field using the `h:message` tag, but how to set a CSS class for the field?

Comment: Did you try https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlInputText.html#setStyleClass-java.lang.String- ?

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993615/highlight-an-inputtext-in-jsf-when-a-validation-error-occurs#10993853?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlight an inputText in JSF when a validation error occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993615/highlight-an-inputtext-in-jsf-when-a-validation-error-occurs)